# Data crawling from websites

Tags: java, csv, web-crawler

I'm new to such type of problem, so I have question about data crawling from websites. I need retrieve data from some website, as I know the data can be retrieved in form of csv or xls file. But how can I get url to download it?

For example, I'm opening some clothes shop and see all assortment, is where some way to receive this data in form of file(csv or some other)?or I need to parse somehow html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Learn the Basics**

**First:** it all depends on the type of website (static / dynamic) and requirements (what kind of data you want to grab and out in your records).

**Second and important one:** you need to learn How to make web request in your preferred language. Also, How to serialize/Deserialize data in various file formats.

Here's a nice post from X Wang on Creating a Java Crawler:

http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/

It should get you started with your purpose.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Second part is understandable for me. I'm just wondering how to get file with content of the site. I understand that I should create request to receive this file and parse it. But request is created basing on some url what should return file with data. So how to know what url should be processed?

Comment: what language you speak?

Comment: I'm speaking about Java

Answer (score 0):

For me I would suggest you use the web scraping tool as it is much easier and more convenient. If you didn't use any other web scraping tools before, I would recommend you to use the web scraping tool directly. It could help you to extract data from websites into Excel or CSV format as you want. If you are interested, you could see this case tutorial to learn more.
[Scrape Data from Airbnb into Excel](http://www.octoparse.com/tutorial/scrape-data-from-airbnb-into-excel/)